# Error while trying to read posted json data in php

Tags: php, json

I have the following problem. When i am trying to read some json data that are posted from an html page, i'm facing with the following error "Trying to get property of non-object on line".

Jquery script to create the json

```
var json = {"data":[]};

json.data.push({serialNumber: $serialNumber, xreosi: $xreosiToPost,
forma: $forma, apolia: $apolia});
```

Jquery for posting to php

```
$.post("page.php",{jsonData: JSON.stringify(json),
customer: $("#cusID").val()},function(data){});
```

PHP file

```
  $json = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
  foreach($json as $value){
    $serialNumber = $value->serialNumber;
    echo $serialNumber;
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thereafter:

```
var json = {"data":[]};

json.data.push({serialNumber: $serialNumber, xreosi: $xreosiToPost,
forma: $forma, apolia: $apolia});
```

You have:
 Object[data][0] = array('serialNumber' => ...);

Need:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['jsonData'][0]);
```

or

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);

foreach($json as $row){
  foreach($row as $value) {
    $serialNumber = $value->serialNumber;
    echo $serialNumber;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode` without second parameter returns result as php object. You have to pass `true` as second parameter. Also your data are in `$json['data']`, not `$json`:

```
$json = json_decode($_POST['jsonData'], true);
foreach($json['data'] as $value) {
    $serialNumber = $value->serialNumber;
    echo $serialNumber;
}
```